# Monitoring who is online?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Using socket.io can I reliably count on `connect` and `disconnect` events for determining who is online and who is lost or closed the connection? Would it be more reliable to tie into the `heartbeat` and determine who is connected on my own.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One directly depends on the other. If heartbeat fails(times out) then socket.io will emit `disconnect` event.

Comment: Ok, was my main question. I didn't know if they were reliable (as using heartbeat) or if the client had to trigger disconnect for that event to fire. Thanks!